# How to access CameraControl from PreviewView in Jetpack

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-camerax

I have the following AndroidView which shows the view from back camera. The 'factory' routine runs once just fine. The 'update' is called when zoom value changes but the camera view doesn't reflect the updated zoom.

```
   val zoom: MutableState<Float> = remember { mutableStateOf(2f) }

   . . . 

   AndroidView(

        factory = {context ->
            val previewView = PreviewView(context)

            val preview = Preview.Builder().build()

            val selector = CameraSelector.Builder()
                .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
                .build()

            preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.surfaceProvider)

            val cam = cameraProviderFuture.get().bindToLifecycle(
                lifecycleOwner,
                selector,
                preview,
            )

            cam.cameraControl.setZoomRatio(zoom)
            println("factory view " + previewView)

            previewView
        },

        update = { view ->
            print("preview view " +view)
            view.controller?.cameraControl?.setZoomRatio(zoom)
            println("updated zoom " + zoom)
        },
        modifier = modifier
    )
```

What is the right way to access the camera control to set the zoom?

Answer (score 0):

Store your zoom level as state, then you'll get a re-composition when that state value changes.

From your code, it's not possible to see where you obtain the zoom level from initially, or how you listen to it changing.

```kotlin
var zoom by remember { mutableStateOf(initialZoomLevel) }

AndroidView(
    ...
)
```

You'll need some sort of listener that can update the zoom value when the user changes it.

Comment: right that's how it is stored (updated question). zoom is updating fine. the camera zoom doesn't change so something wrong with - view.controller?.cameraControl?.setZoomRatio(zoom)

Comment: have you verified the value of zoom is actually changing?

Comment: yes zoom value changes as per println log